# LAN transfer speed

Tags: lan, transfer, download-speed

When I try to download various files from various hdd`s hosted on my Ubuntu 13.10 server, I get a maximum of 60Mbps. These files were downloading with arround 330Mbps on my old server. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded the kernel to **3.11.0-12-generic** and I am getting an incredible constant speed of around **930 Mbps**.

Comment: May I ask what provider you are using to get over 900 MBPS?!?